# How to Track Connected Components in a Graph when Deleting Nodes

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Suppose you have a graph G, and you want to support the following operations:

- `addNode(Node n)`
- `addEdge(Node n1, Node n2)`
- `deleteNode(Node n)`

Now I want to track after every operation what the connected components of my graph are. If I only had to support `addNode` and `addEdge`, I would use a Union-Find data structure to maintain this information after every operation.

However, how does one support deletion operations? My current thought is that I must run several BFS operations on my graph to recompute all the connected components of the graph again.

Is there a more efficient way to support the `delete` operation?

Comment: Have you looked at [dynamic connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_connectivity), i.e., incremental connected components?

Comment: Ahh thanks, this was the resource I was looking for. Looks like the solution to the problem is fairly difficult...